# Determining popular tags using mysql?

Tags: php, mysql, tags

I have two tables:

```
posts{id,post,tag_id,date}
tags{id,tag,date}
```

I want to retrieve the most popular tags used from the post table, used in the last 12 hours.

¿How can I achieve this?
Thanks.

Comment: What does the `tags` date signify?

Comment: when the tags was created!! im more concerned about with the date in the post table, to get the latest 12 hours

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this should work:

```
SELECT tags.tag, count(*) AS count
    FROM posts INNER JOIN tags
    ON (posts.tag_id = tags.id)
    WHERE posts.date >= SUBTIME(NOW(), '12:00:00')
    GROUP BY tags.id
    ORDER BY count(*) DESC
```

I tested with 3 posts with 'SQL' as tag created within 12h and 2 posts with 'PHP' as tag but only one of them created within 12h. The query above then returns:

```
tag count
SQL 3
PHP 1
```

Comment: thanks, but this is giving me an empty set, i do have tags that have been created like an hour ago, and have been used quite a lot!!!

Comment: Ok and you also have posts created within 12 hours? What are the types of your columns?

Answer (score 2):

To get the most popular tags in descending order from the last 12 hours you could do this:

```
SELECT tag  
FROM tags 
WHERE id IN (
    SELECT tag_id FROM posts WHERE date >= SUBTIME(NOW(), '12:00:00')
)
ORDER BY COUNT(id) DESC
```

Comment: He meant `SUBTIME`. Next time google `mysql SUB_TIME` and you would have found the answer in 2 seconds.

Comment: @webbiedave: Thanks for the correction. I've updated the answer. Sorry about the typo...was on my mobile :S